# Unable to extract graph data (nodes,links) from json in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

After days of effort, I have finally created my first d3.js layout. But now I want to segregate data and script. I was trying to use JSON to keep data and extract from it. But it didn't work. Please help.

I tried this, but then it started failing:

```
d3.json("sample.json", function(data) {
  var link = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "links")
            .selectAll("line")
            .data(data.links)
            .enter().append("line")
            .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

var node = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "nodes")
            .selectAll("circle")
            .data(data.nodes)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("r", 5)
            .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
            .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", dragstarted)
            .on("drag", dragged)
            .on("end", dragended));
...
)};
```

Here is the complete code I am working on.

JSFIDDLE : [d3_graph_labelled_edge.js](http://jsfiddle.net/seemant/0d7en4po/138/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invalid JSON. After formatting (removing last line commas and replacing single quotes with double):

```
{
"nodes": [{
        "name": "NE1",
        "full_name": "NE1",
        "type": 2,
        "slug": "12.3",
        "entity": "company",
        "img_hrefD": "",
        "img_hrefL": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "NE2",
        "full_name": "NE2",
        "type": 2,
        "slug": "12.4",
        "entity": "company",
        "img_hrefD": "",
        "img_hrefL": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "NE3",
        "full_name": "NE3",
        "type": 2,
        "slug": "12.3",
        "entity": "company",
        "img_hrefD": "",
        "img_hrefL": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "NE4",
        "full_name": "NE4",
        "type": 2,
        "slug": "12.1",
        "entity": "company",
        "img_hrefD": "",
        "img_hrefL": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "NE5",
        "full_name": "NE5",
        "type": 2,
        "slug": "12.0",
        "entity": "company",
        "img_hrefD": "",
        "img_hrefL": ""
    }
],
"links": [{
        "source": 0,
        "target": 1,
        "value": 1,
        "distance": 15,
        "a": "123",
        "z": "111"
    },
    {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 2,
        "value": 1,
        "distance": 15,
        "a": "123",
        "z": "111"
    },
    {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 3,
        "value": 1,
        "distance": 15,
        "a": "123",
        "z": "111"
    },
    {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 2,
        "value": 1,
        "distance": 15,
        "a": "123",
        "z": "111"
    },
    {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 3,
        "value": 1,
        "distance": 15,
        "a": "123",
        "z": "111"
    },
    {
        "source": 2,
        "target": 3,
        "value": 1,
        "distance": 15,
        "a": "123",
        "z": "111"
    },
    {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 4,
        "value": 1,
        "distance": 15,
        "a": "123",
        "z": "111"
    }
]
}
```

Here's a plunkr using the above JSON: http://plnkr.co/edit/vRrYyjH3mtPz8vEuTZKx?p=preview

Recommendation: Use [JSON Lint](https://jsonlint.com/) for validation.

Hope this helps.